# Center one equation of many in align?

Tags: amsmath, align

I have the following `align` enviroment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Here we see
\begin{align}
\text{cat} &= \text{dog}\\
\text{dog} &= cute
\intertext{and if we remove}
\text{dog}\\
\intertext{we get}
\text{cat} &= cute
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Which creates:

[image: An unaligned equation]

How do I center equation 3 while keeping everything else aligned? I can get close by putting in an `&` in the real equation, but it's still not perfectly centered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `gathered` environment. Better using [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) instead of [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) (it's an extension that loads `amsmath` and fixes two bugs in it). Here is how:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{catxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} &= \text{dog}\\
\text{dog} &= \text{cute}\\
\intertext{and if we remove}
\begin{gathered}
\text{and if we remove dog}
\end{gathered} \\
\intertext{we get}
\text{cat} &= \text{cute}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This looks like it works more properly. I'll try `mathtools`.

Comment: It's an extension to `amsmath`: it loads it, and by default fixes two bugs in amsmath.

Comment: Yep, it worked though I had to figure out `\mathclap` (I think). Otherwise it wasn't centering.

Comment: @bombcar note that that this doesn't actually answer the question (although it makes a reasonable layout on the MWE) It puts the centre of the dog line at the alignment point which only approximately centres the line as cat=cute have similar length, if you change the first line to `\text{catxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} &= \text{dog}\\ ` you'll see the dog line moves using this approach but stays if it is set in `equation`

Comment: @David Carlisle: You're perfectly right. Actually I added \clap \ or \mathclap when I observed the "gathered" part wasn't really centred. It must have been because of some other code in my file, which I've deleted since then. So simply using the gathered environment gives the same result as equation, but it seems to me more natural to use gathered, and you can have several gathered lines.

Comment: @Bernard I meant use equation as in the other answer which takes it out of the alignment, if you use gathered here it is centred  in the left side of the alignment not centred on the text width.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Here we see
\begin{align}
\text{cat} &= \text{dog}\\
\text{dog} &= cute
\intertext{and if we remove
\begin{equation}dog\end{equation}
we get\vspace{-\baselineskip}}\\
\text{cat} &= cute
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh! You can put `equation` inside `intertext`. It works but seems naughty somehow!

Comment: @bombcar well i can't say I've ever done it before but it was worth a try. It doesn't really work it makes the first following line of the align to be not numbered, which is why I add the `\\ ` and back up a row so the cat line gets numbered. If you look at the chat site you'll see a comment about that:-)

Comment: It's close enough for what I needed, so it's good enough for me. I'm kind of surprised that `amsmath` doesn't already have some default for it, though.

Comment: @bombcar: I modified my answer to take David Carlisle's remark into account. It makes me coming back to my initial answer, which was very close to his's. Gathered offers the possibility to have several lines centred within one environment, which equation can't do.

Comment: @Bernard no this answer centres the dog line on the text block, so it is unlike yours (but it is probably an abuse of the ams code:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle: you're right. I misinterpreted the exact meaning of the gathered environment. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: cute, but the vertical distance between equation numbers (2) and (3) is less than that between (3) and (4), which isn't what one would expect.  (i didn't know that would work either.  will have to experiment.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes I know a better fix would be to not have the `\\ ` and the negative vspace (which as you note isn't exact) and instead figure out why the first equation number after the construct is suppressed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- okay.  i'll see if i can figure out what's happening, but probably not until at least the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it seems to be safe to use `\multispan`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\equationinalign}[1]{%
  \multispan{2}%
  \hfill$\displaystyle{#1}$\hfill
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\hspace*{\fill}\smash{\vrule depth 10cm width 0.1pt}\hspace*{\fill}

Here we see
\begin{align}
\text{cat} &= \text{dog}\\
\text{dog} &= \text{cute}\\
\intertext{and if we remove}
\equationinalign{\text{dog}}
\intertext{we get}
\text{cat} &= \text{cute}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]