# To get one line of equation disregarded during the alignment process in align environment

Tags: amsmath, align

Couldn't find any answer to this question on anywhere. I have this one particular solution in my hands, which helps only if the equation to be disregarded for alignment is the first or the last of the array of equations, which is simply:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{gather} % or gather*
        2 + 5 + 123 + 45 = 175\\ % the equation I am taking out of alignment
        \begin{aligned}
             2 + 3 &= 5\\
            11 + 5 &= 16
        \end{aligned}
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Which doesn't really look good to my eyes. Works though; works exactly as I hoped it to, and looks exactly as I wanted it to.

Then again, what would be the proper way to do it, which preferably also manages to deal with a not-aligned equation in between, rather than just at the beginning or the end? Heard and read about this ancient `\noalign` command, but also read that it is *not supported* or something like that.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs It doesn't seem tedious, but useless and even distracting to me. Now the code has almost twice as many lines, more levels of indentation, for nothing of worth. Unless turned into a robot, a regular human wouldn't give compiler errors for such, and even find them redundant. Personally, I'd be more willing to pay attention to a simpler code as the previous one, than to this new one.

Comment: You are are lot more likely to get help if you do as Jubobs ask. Then those answering does not have to add anything to the mwe, they can copy it and work on it immediately.

Comment: Just one line in your preamble that you don't tell us about can affect the answer. A MWE is almost always useful because it (and your typesetting engine, e.g. `pdflatex`) unambiguously tells us what the problem is. A question without an MWE is, in many cases, akin to asking what the sound of one hand clapping is like.

Comment: Exactly, there have been so many cases here, where users have not told everything resulting in tedious commenting back and forth until we reached an mwe that actually showed the real problem.

Comment: @Jubobs *almost* is the keyword there, this most decidedly isn't one of such cases. Here, I give it to you, that you may be right that this is a *very* exceptional case, that it is not part of your *almost*. Now, I'd like you to be honest and answer this sub-question of mine: Was what you have requested really necessary for this particular question?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin I'm not much for counterfactual history, but I can tell you that I wouldn't have upvoted your answer if you hadn't edited it to add an MWE. Consider it a form of politeness (see [daleif's earlier comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219779/to-get-one-line-of-equation-disregarded-during-the-alignment-process-in-align-en#comment516051_219779)). I can assure you that, on TeX.SE, you'll be much better off if you endeavour having an MWE in your question. I rest my case.

Comment: I would also add that it should be common decency to make a question as easy as possible to answer. Some questions can be answered of the top of your head. But whenever I'm at a computer, I always compile and test before I answer. So by providing something that compiles without additions makes my time more worthwhile to spend on a question.

Comment: I am sure I would have put down the preamble commands, if my question was about a problem I was struggling with. This is not one of such; the code extract I had provided was even simply just a worked method I have offered my own, meaning that it has absolutely no issues in it. I don't feel any thankful for that upvote, it wasn't that I was seeking for it as I followed your request, rather immediately. I was simply being polite, yet I felt like I should talk back, because it was one of those StackExchange-Bot type responses I had been seeing in other portals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\mathclap` from [the `mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools):

[image]

### References:

- [TUGboat 2001: A complement to \smash, \llap, and\rlap -- Alexander R. Perlis](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Eaperlis/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \mathclap{2 + 5 + 123 + 45 = 175}\\ % the equation I am taking out of alignment
         2 + 3 &= 5\\
        11 + 5 &= 16
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much better than mine, and works if the unaligned equation is in the middle, too.

Comment: If one combined it with environ one could turn this into an centeredeq env instead of having to wrap it in a macro (thus hiding the macro)

Comment: I am not certain about what `\mathclap` does, but I guess it places the equation inside into a zero-width box, then centres its contents, is that right? Nice looking by the way, thanks for that.

Comment: One caveat to this solution: if the eq is long, align will not know and will not move the eq number

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Yep that is exactly what it does. Have added a link where this and other related macros are described in more detail.

Comment: @PeterGrill Which is why it actually produces something similar to the second alternative in the other answer, with the only difference that the equation is centred around the left hand side of the equals signs of the other two equations. For example; try this solution with three times the exact same equation, you'll see what I mean. *I am confused.* This actually wasn't what I wanted, of course. Then again, this still complies with every aspect that the question title asks for, i.e. the alignment-omitted equation doesn't impact the alignment. That's why, I'll keep this as the chosen answer.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Not sure I fully understand you comment, but there is also `\mathrlap` and `\mathllap` (which gives outputs the other alignment option pictured below).  If that is desired I can update the answer with `\mathllap`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Try aligning the following three equations: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 - 10 = 5`, same, and again the same. Take the first one out of alignment using this technique. You shall see that the last two are aligned (fine), and the first one shifted to the right until its zero-width box gets aligned as well, as a left hand side of an equation (not fine).

Comment: @PeterGrill, try replacing `2+3` with something much longer. Then you'll see the problem

Comment: It seems that Mikes answer is actually better, but it cannot produce a numbered line. And it gives more vertical space.

Answer (score 4):

The first alternative below is close, but not perfect (and definitely an abuse of `\intertext`). No equation number is added to the middle equation as a result. The second alternative (from [Center one equation of many in align?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165007)) puts all the unaligned content to one side of the alignment character, which probably isn't desirable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
2 + 3 &= 5
\intertext{\centering\(2 + 5 + 123 + 45 = 175\)}
11 + 5 &= 16
\end{align}
\begin{align}
2 + 3 &= 5 \\
\begin{gathered}2 + 5 + 123 + 45 = 175\end{gathered} \\
11 + 5 &= 16
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mike, could you retry (I'm not at pc) and use the gathered env instead of the intertext? There was a question about this very thing earlier today, where the answer used gathered (AFAIR)

Comment: It's not the same result, since the gathered content goes on one side of the alignment character. Will edit accordingly, maybe there's a tweak to be made yet.

Comment: No it doesn't, see this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165014/3929

Comment: There, I see 'and if we remove dog' all to the left of the '=' signs on equations 1, 2, and 4. That's what I meant.

Comment: No, you're right, didn't read the comments carefully enough. I think I'd see if I could turn Peters answer into an environment (as I like that better as an interface)