# \mathclap does not center equation in align

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

I want to center an equation inside an `align` environment, since it otherwise would push the other equations too far to the right, outside of my `tcolorbox`.

As suggested in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219784/59521) answer, one should be able to do so with the `\mathclap` command from `mathtools`.

Obviously this does not work here:

[image]

MWE:

```
% !TeX program=lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{align}
        \dot{\epsilon}^{\text{eq}} &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\dot{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^{\text{p}}:\dot{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^{\text{p}}} && \text{(an equation in plasticity)} \\
        %
        \mathclap{
        \sigma^Y(z,\epsilon_{\gamma},\epsilon_{\alpha},T) = (1-f(z))\sigma^y_{\gamma}(\epsilon_{\gamma},T)+f(z)\sigma^y_{\alpha}(\epsilon_{\alpha},T)
        }\label{gln:ultimate-stress-iso}
        \end{align}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually it is doing exactly what it is suppose to. It is centering the equation at the current point. There are not alignment markers on this line, thus we have a single left hand part of an alignment column, aka the mathclap is centered under the left part of the = in the line above, as seen in the image. BTW: you should never ever use `\text` like this, it does not do what you think. Uwe `\mathrm` or `\textup` (long story short, `\text` will output italic text is the surrounding context is italic, like inside a theorem, we do not want that, we want upright always)

Comment: Is there a way to manually place an "alignment marker" on the center of the line? I ended up inserting a `\hspace{6cm}` inside the `\mathclap` for now, which at least approximately centers the equation and leaves the rest as is.

Comment: @daleif As a side note: Is there any other drawback from the misuse of `\text` than the one you mentioned? I never typeset math in an italic environment.

Comment: The main problem is education. In the end you probably end up passing on your code to others, and then they think this is the proper method to use. Or, what happens if a publisher ask you to change some layouts, so some of these end up being italic. Better to remove bad habits than to have to clean up afterwards. It is also when others see your code on this site, they'll think this is the proper way to get stuff upright, but it is not. Another thing would be if the math and text font differed a lot.

Comment: Good points. Unfortunately, a simple search-replace would replace the correct `\text` for in-equation comments like above, too.

Comment: Exactly, therefore it is not a good idea to use `\text` for anything other than textual comments. I often never use `\text`, add it inside relevant macros (for example I have one that produces `\qquad\text{#1}`, making the code cleaner)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I guess it would be better to either don't use `\mathclap` at all and remove the `&&` prior to your text (as this is really pushing your equations to the left) or to use a `\mathllap` on some parts of the second equation. The following is an example showing both options.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{align}
        \dot{\epsilon}^{\text{eq}} &=
        \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\dot{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^{\text{p}}:\dot{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^{\text{p}}}
        \quad\text{(an equation in plasticity)} \\
        %
        \mathllap{\sigma^Y(z,\epsilon_{\gamma},\epsilon_{\alpha},}T) &= (1-f(z))\sigma^y_{\gamma}(\epsilon_{\gamma}^,T)+f(z)\sigma^y_{\alpha}(\epsilon_{\alpha},T)
        \label{gln:ultimate-stress-iso}
        \end{align}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{align}
        \dot{\epsilon}^{\text{eq}} &=
        \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\dot{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^{\text{p}}:\dot{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^{\text{p}}}
        \quad\text{(an equation in plasticity)} \\
        %
        \sigma^Y(z,\epsilon_{\gamma},\epsilon_{\alpha},T) &= (1-f(z))\sigma^y_{\gamma}(\epsilon_{\gamma}^,T)+f(z)\sigma^y_{\alpha}(\epsilon_{\alpha},T)
        \label{gln:ultimate-stress-iso}
        \end{align}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Like you found out in your comment, you could as well use `\mathrlap` on some parts of the long equation:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{align}
        \dot{\epsilon}^{\text{eq}} &=
        \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\dot{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^{\text{p}}:\dot{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}^{\text{p}}}
        &&\text{(an equation in plasticity)} \\
        %
        \sigma^Y(z,\epsilon_{\gamma},\epsilon_{\alpha},T) &=
        (1-f(z))\sigma^y_{\gamma}(\epsilon_{\gamma}^,T)+\mathrlap{f(z)\sigma^y_{\alpha}(\epsilon_{\alpha},T)}
        \label{gln:ultimate-stress-iso}
        \end{align}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer the text behind the equations to be aligned via `&&`. There are actually more relatively short equations with text behind them and having these descriptions aligned looks better...

Comment: Your answer made me realize, I can get exactly what I want, if I just put the last summand of the second equation inside `\mathrlap`. Maybe you want to add that to your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3):

I think the real remedy consists in (a) not using `\mathclap` and, more importantly, (b) not using `align`. Instead, use a `gather` environment.

Separately, consider using `\tfrac` ("text style fraction") in the first equation.

And, since you appear to be using LuaLaTeX, don't write  `\boldsymbol{...}`. Instead, be sure to load the `unicode-math` package and to write `\symbf{...}`. Similarly, don't write `\text{p}` and `\text{eq}`. Instead, write `\symup{eq}` and `symup{p}`.

[image]

```
% !TeX program=lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{gather}
\dot{\epsilon}^{\symup{eq}} 
= \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}\dot{\symbf{\epsilon}}^{\symup{p}}:
  \dot{\symbf{\epsilon}}^{\symup{p}}} 
\qquad\text{(an equation in plasticity)} \\
\sigma^Y(z,\epsilon_{\gamma},\epsilon_{\alpha},T) 
= (1-f(z))\sigma^y_{\gamma}(\epsilon_{\gamma},T)
  +f(z)\sigma^y_{\alpha}(\epsilon_{\alpha},T)
\label{gln:ultimate-stress-iso}
\end{gather}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very compliments for both the two answers.+1.

Comment: @Sebastiano  - Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the hints on the `unicode-math` commands. However, I specifically asked for align since I want all (there are more) equations except the overlong second aligned at `=`. It looks messy otherwise.

Comment: @Christoph90 - In that case, you should definitely go with the solution shown in equations 3 and 4 of [@skillmon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424680/5001).